# LibreOffice Calc: export portion or region as .csv?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, libreoffice-calc

How can I highlight a portion of a large spreadsheet and just export that portion as a .csv file? Is this possible?

Tried highlighting section then 'Save as...' .csv, but it saved the whole sheet.

Tried copy-n-paste to text document, but it didn't surround fields with quotes, or separate with commas. However, it did just save the selected region.

Tried copy-n-paste to Calc spreadsheet. This worked, but wondered if there were a way with fewer steps, that didn't involve a separate, new spreadsheet.

Using LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 in Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks!

-Kevin